# How to remove the border of image when it is shown as unavailable?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to remove the border when an image is not yet loaded but the height and width are set? 
I am creating a lazy loading so the icon will be centred inside as a background image, until image loads.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgoqYv

same code in the snippet also

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  /* border: 0 !important; */
    background-image: url(https://i0.wp.com/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.site/nonexistant.jpg" />
```

Comment: Don’t use a non-existing image, use a small transparent GIF or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the "broken image". But you can work around it. For example you can replace the broken image with some little javascript:

```
<img src="idonotexist.jpg" onerror="this.src='trans.png';">
```

Of course you can write it cleaner in js instead inside the `img` tag.

Alternatively, you can work with pseudo classes to hide the broken image etc. Have a look here: https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/